# Downloading Map Tiles from Griffiths Valuation of Northern Ireland?

Tags: data, tiles, qgis-3, united-kingdom, history

I would like to download map tiles of Northern Ireland associated with Griffiths Valuation of Ireland in 1867.  These maps have details of property leased by individuals, including farm fields and houses.  These are available on the web at  http://www.askaboutireland.ie/griffith-valuation/index.xml?action=doNameSearch&Submit.x=31&Submit.y=11&familyname=Burns&firstname=James&baronyname=&countyname=DOWN&unionname=&parishname= then click on one of the map icons.    I have used tif copies of the maps then displayed on the web site, ported successfully to QGIS 3.2. But I want something more extensive and useable with good resolution at higher zoom levels to look at individual farms within particular townlands.  I might be able to do this using the tiles which are evident in the displays.  I use georeferencing to line up the resulting 1850s OS tif maps with a more modern map.

Comment: interesting resource! i see the error 'returned image is flawed' in qgis once i add it as an XYZ tile provider, then zoom in far enough - is that what you're referring to?  it seems ok up to about scale 1:6000 or zoom level 16. jpegs will always look a bit blurry and unsharp if compression is high.

Comment: Yes a great resource indeed, packed with data.  This is an encouraging reply Steven... thanks so much and more later.

Comment: @Steven Kay:I am unable to get the tiles loaded from the Griffiths site. Using the Browser Panel I inserted many variants of the Griffiths URL always appending: “/{z}/{x}/{y}.png”  I have also tried the entire process with various settings of CRS.  EPSG 3857 is ln Properties when the raster is created. I read in Stackexchange that this QGIS process sometimes will not work.  Perhaps I should try python script language, but I do not know which parameters need listed. Could you possibly list the procedure you used to load the tiles?  And any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the site as an **XYZ provider**. Make sure you check with the site for its usage, copyright and licensing policy.

In QGIS 3, go into the **Data Source Manager**, Browser tab, then right-click XYZ Tiles, New Connection.

I don't seem to be able to get QuickMapServices to work on QGIS 3.2 on the Mac, so I use XYZ tile services as a workaround. But if you can get QuickMapServices to work, you could use that too - this way's probably easier though.

Enter the following URL. I chose the first map on the list, you may need to tweak this depending on which map layer you want.

> http://griffiths.askaboutireland.ie/gv4/single_layer/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg

[image]

The {z}, {x} and {y} are place holders for the zoom level, and tile x and y coordinates. QGIS will fill in these values for you as you zoom and pan the map.

The site only appears to have tiles to level 16 - if you zoom in any further, you'll get error messages. So set the maximum zoom level to 16. That will stop you sending the server lots of tile requests it won't be able to handle.

Because the maps were from scans, it's normal to only zoom in part of the way - for each additional zoom level, the storage and processing requirements go up by a factor of 4. This means the maps will be good to about a scale of 1:6000 or thereabouts.

They're JPEGs, so compression may be the reason for the slightly blurry look / lack of sharpness.

You can also add OpenStreetMap (OSM) using the same technique - I use this to provide a fast basemap for navigation and zooming in, then enable the Griffiths layer when I've zoomed to an area of interest. For example with OSM

> http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

Comment: WOW Steven!  I cannot use the "t" word, but congrats on your deep knowledge.  It worked like a dream.  Slan agus beannacht!